# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string- can't find a solution

Tags: php, object, post, error-handling, json

I have the following code:

```
if ($difference)
{
    $.post("recover_functions/upload_photos.php",
           {upload:$difference},
           function(response)
           {
               alert($difference);
               if (response.status)
                   alert("Successfully uploaded photos");
               else
                   alert(response);
            });
}
```

The alert will display:

```
{"difference":"[{\"aid\":\"100000543443572_1073741825\",\"backdated_time\":null,\"caption\":\"\",\"link\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.facebook.com\\\/photo.php?fbid=614604095234366&set=a.614604001901042.1073741825.100000543443572&type=1\",\"pid\":\"100000543443572_2384218\",\"place_id\":null}]"}
```

And I get the `POST request like this:

```
$string_diff = $_POST['upload'];
$array_diff  = json_decode($string_diff);

echo $array_diff;
```

Not the response is `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.
Please help, I have a deadline (1 hour) and I can't get this working.

Comment: use print_r($array_diff); instead of doing echo statement. Because $array_diff is a standard class object array and it cannot be echoed using echo statement\

Comment: `deadline` : This is definitely not your job if aren't able to solve this

Comment: @hek2mgl Sometimes when I am in a hurry, I don't see obvious mistakes normally. I am a little desperate

Comment: Note that in such situations it is better to delay the deadline. hurry isn't the programmers best friend. however, good luck!

Comment: @hek2mgl the deadline could not be delayed, since I needed to present the prject at that time. I was a little desperate and omitted that I had echo-ed an object. Thank you

Comment: I hope your presentation was a success! ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl yeah, they were quite happy with my project. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like an array, you can't echo a stdClass object. You could `var_dump($array_diff)` and echo specific properties like so:

```
echo $array_diff->my_property;
```

Comment: You can if it implements toString.

Comment: @Sherlock StdClass doesn't implement __toString

Comment: I was making a general comment on his statements that objects can't be echoed.

Comment: @Sherlock Sorry, you're right. I edited my post - should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

After `$array_diff = json_decode($string_diff);`, `$array_diff` is an object, so you can't just echo it. Try something like

```
echo $array_diff->your_property;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.print-r.php) to print a human-readable information about a variable:

```
print_r($array_diff);
```